# Is it possible to recover expando-attributes from asp.net hiddenfield controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, hidden-field

Have a simple piece of markup like this:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnPreReqPhaseType" runat="server" Value="not set" ClientIDMode="Static" data-Custom="SingleOrDouble" />
```

and wanted to recover the data-Custom text in the C# code-behind as i assumed there would be a getAttribute method or an Attributes collection...unfortunately not for the hidden field!!

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think using `asp:HiddenField` will even compile with custom attribute, you should be getting something like

> Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField' does not have a public
>   property named 'data-Custom'.

but using

```
<input type="hidden"  ID="hdnPreReqPhaseType" runat="server" Value="not set" ClientIDMode="Static" data-Custom="SingleOrDouble" />
```

Should give you a nice

```
hdnPreReqPhaseType.Attributes["data-Custom"]
```

In the server-side C# code.

Comment: Thanks Yuriy - that was indeed correct!!  I thought about that solution myself over the weekend and indeed had that problem you said - just had not tried to run it before i posted the question (that is a valuable lesson too :-)